# Add multiple val to input from class

Tags: jquery, input

I have many div elements with same class names. I want the user to be able to choose some of them in to a form input text element (value). So far I only made it put the last clicked one.

```
  <div class="post">
    <div class="addThis">A</div>
    <div class="addThis">B</div>
    <div class="addThis">C</div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="Choice">

jQuery('.addThis').click(function() {
var x = jQuery(this).closest('.post').find('addThis').text();
var y = jQuery("#Choice").val(x);
```

The var y is there because I tried to do something with it. But all attempts failed. Tried with

```
var t += y;
jQuery("#Choice").val(t);
```

and a lot that I already forgot

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you trying to do with the text?

Comment: I try to get the text of the div class="addThis" to be added to a form input field. but only those that are clicked on. Now this code rewrites it everytime. thus adding only the last clicked text.

Comment: Have you thought about just using a series of checkboxes like `<input type="checkbox" id="chkA" class="addThis" value="A" /><label for="chkA">A</label>`

Comment: checkbox is not really it. but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your trying to do:

```
$('.addThis').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).html();
    $("#Choice").val($("#Choice").val() + x);
});
```

Comment: yes exactly!. thank you.. I will still see if I can make a element to be able added only once.

Comment: @Mik_A The right word you are looking for is *concatenate*

Comment: Sure. but I see it as a shopping basket, therefore added :)